# Server side encryption with customer provided key in a single bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a multi tenant application where we separate the tenant data in separate folders in the same bucket. Mainly because of bucket limits
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Now we want to support server side encryption with customer provided key where each tenant provide their separate keys.

My question is whether S3 supports customer provided keys for separate folders in the same bucket.

As per the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-java-sdk.html i don't see any problem in achieving this.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely supported, encryption happens at the object level and you can specify how each object is supposed to be encrypted in the `PutObject` request.

To do that, you use these two headers:

- `x-amz-server-side-encryption` set this one to `aws:kms`
- `x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id` set this one to the key ID of the customer specific key.

Keep in mind, that the principal that does the `PutObject` needs to both know the key id and have `kms:encrypt` permissions on it. Depending on the amount of customers you have this may or may not be a scalable solution.

**Reference**

- [PutObject API-Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax)